# JQuery animate breaks the script but without it the script works

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have written this Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var offset = $("#menu_list").offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= offset) {
            $("#menu_list").removeClass("menu_list_init");
            $("#menu_list").addClass("menu_overlay");

            $("#menu_list").animate({
                opacity: 0.25;
            }, 5000, function() {
                //nothing here
            });
        }
        else if($("#menu_list").hasClass("menu_overlay")) {
            $("#menu_list").removeClass("menu_overlay");
            $("#menu_list").addClass("menu_list_init");
        }
    });
});
```

Before putting the animate function in there the code was doing what it was supposed too, that is applying some classes when an element reaches the top of the page, it was making the menu which is in the middle stretch to cover the width of the screen.

I thought I might try out using the animate function in there, so I took the stock code from the JQuery website, however, it doesn't work at all once I put it in there...perhaps there is an obvious reason as too why but I can't see it...

Comment: Please supply a jsfiddle. Have you checked your browser console?

Comment: @Thew I should have checked the console, wasting everyone's time, I apologise lol, it was the semicolon after the opacity property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SyntaxError: missing } after property list"

```
opacity: 0.25;
```

remove the ; after the 0.25

Comment: Thank you, it was the syntax error :) perhaps I should have used firebug or something, thank you so much :) it works perfectly.